# Price comparison - python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

Hi guys i am trying to create a program in python that compares prices from websites but i cant get the prices. I have managed to ge the title of the product and the quantity using the code bellow.

```
page = requests.get(urls[7],headers=Headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find("h1",{"class" : "Titlestyles__TitleStyles-sc-6rxg4t-0 fDKOTS"}).get_text().strip()
quantity = soup.find("li", class_="quantity").get_text().strip()
total_price = soup.find('div', class_='Pricestyles__ProductPriceStyles-sc-118x8ec-0 fzwZWj price')
print(title)
print(quantity)
print(total_price)
```

Iam trying to get the price from this website (Iam creating a program do look for diper prices lol) https://www.drogasil.com.br/fralda-huggies-tripla-protecao-tamanho-m.html .

the price is not coming even if i get the text it always says that its  nonetype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the information is built up via javascript from data stored in `<script>` sections in the HTML. You can access this directly by searching for it and using Python's JSON library to decode it into a Python structure. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.drogasil.com.br/fralda-huggies-tripla-protecao-tamanho-m.html'
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')
data = json.loads(script.text)

title = data['name']
total_price = data['offers']['price']

quantity = soup.find("li", class_="quantity").get_text().strip()

print(title)
print(quantity)
print(total_price)
```

Giving you:

```
HUGGIES FRALDAS DESCARTAVEL INFANTIL TRIPLA PROTECAO TAMANHO M COM 42 UNIDADES
42 Tiras
38.79
```

I recommend you add `print(data)` to see what other information is available.